# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - how to create a new form field

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is there any way to create a new form field and add it to the available fields section? I need to add a new text field to the form and pass it over Dynamics CRM to a database. Thanks

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes on this question. I for one was interested in this; obviously I know that one can create a field by adding an attribute to the entity but I was interested to know if there was any way to create one on the form itself but not the entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CRM:

1. Settings
2. Customisation
3. Customise Entities
4. Open the entity you want to add the field to
5. Attributes
6. New

This opens a window where you can add an attribute (field) to and entity.

If you want to see this on a form you need to add it to the "Forms and views" afterwards.